# img attributes stripped from Podio Webform Description

Tags: podio

I've implemented several Podio webforms in the past via the embed-code, but now we have a strange issue.

We have a html img tag in the "Description" text, but the image attributes are completely stripped when embedded in our website (= the website source code shows just  instead of

Has this functionality been deprecated? I'm 99.99% sure this worked in the past.

PS: I know you recently implemented the target="_blank" functionality (which is great by the way :-) ) so I was thinking this might be related?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for letting us know -- it did indeed work before we changed our sanitization rules to allow `target="_blank"`. I've add a few more standard attributes to the sanitization whitelist (aria, src, title, alt, width and height) that should address the problem with images as well.

We'll have this update out for you and our other webform users within the next day or so.